# Como traduzir os termos técnicos «Pessoa Física» e «Pessoa Jurídica» para inglês?

Tags: tradução-inglês

Estou começando a migração de um sistema, e uma das regras é que agora todos o termos do banco de dados devem ser em inglês.

Alguns são bem simples:

- cliente => customer
- usuario => user
- perfil => profile
- permissao => permission

Mas como traduzir *Pessoa Física* e *Pessoa Jurídica*?

Eu havia pesquisado e achei como *Natural Person* e *Legal Person*.

Seria isso mesmo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, está correto.

É possível ser mais claro e usar [**juridical person**](https://thelawdictionary.org/juridical-person/):

> Entity, as a firm, that is not a single natural person, as a human being, authorized by law with duties and rights, recognized as a legal authority having a distinct identity, a legal personality. Also known as **artificial person, juridical entity, juristic person, or legal person.**

(A fonte, linkada, é o dicionário legal [mais usado nos EUA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%27s_Law_Dictionary), mas o grifo é meu.)

No entanto, esse termo parece [estar caindo](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=legal+person%2Cjuridical+person%2Clegal+entity%2Cjuridical+entity&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Clegal%20person%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blegal%20person%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLegal%20Person%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cjuridical%20person%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bjuridical%20person%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BJuridical%20Person%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BJuridical%20person%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Clegal%20entity%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blegal%20entity%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLegal%20Entity%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLegal%20entity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cjuridical%20entity%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bjuridical%20entity%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BJuridical%20Entity%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Clegal%20person%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blegal%20person%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLegal%20Person%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cjuridical%20person%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bjuridical%20person%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BJuridical%20Person%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BJuridical%20person%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Clegal%20entity%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blegal%20entity%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLegal%20Entity%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLegal%20entity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cjuridical%20entity%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bjuridical%20entity%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BJuridical%20Entity%3B%2Cc0) no desuso:

[image]

O termo **entidade legal** ([*legal entity*](https://thelawdictionary.org/legal-entity/)) engloba tanto a [*natural person*](https://thelawdictionary.org/natural-person/) (um ser humano, pessoa física) quanto a *juridical person*, mas é claramente o termo usado com mais frequência hoje em dia - e dicionários como o [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/legal/legal%20entity) e [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/legal-entity) inclusive apresentam definições que não incluem pessoas físicas, e.g.,

> an entity (as a corporation or labor union) having under the law rights and responsibilities and especially the capacity to sue and be sued

Comment: Muito obrigado ja me forneceu alguns nortel, de fato `legal entity` creio que vou usar. So aguardar mais um pouco.

Comment: No fim e fiquei apenas com entity mesmo :D

Comment: Me descupla mas eu nunca usei juridical na minha vida, e sou tradutora jurídica por assim dizer. Simplesmente, nos textos não se usa. Se usa: legal entity. a legal entity is not a natural pessoa (pessoa física). A natural person is a human being. A legal entity não engloba natural person.

Comment: Oi @Lambie , não há do que se desculpar. Apenas me baseei no dicionário jurídico disponível online. Acredito que o dicionário ainda é bem estabelecido, mas a versão online é antiga e, portanto, possivelmente defasada. O termo "juridical" está correto também e, como sua própria resposta coloca, "legal entity" na verdade incluiria pessoas (mas não de acordo com o Merriam-Webster e Cambridge). De qualquer forma, seu comentário sobre o uso atual é valioso e, pesquisando um pouco mais nesse sentido, de fato encontrei outras evidências de que "legal entity" pode mesmo ser a melhor alternativa. Thx!

Comment: Caro amigo, juridical entity sim está no dicionário. Mas não se usa muito. A legal entity is not physical human beings It's a legal person (company, corporation etc.). Sou ganha-pão com esse termos faz muitos anos.

Comment: @Lambie, eu sei - se você checar é justamente o que adicionei à minha resposta. Como disse, agradeço tua contribuição.

Answer (score 2):

**Pessoa jurídica** é **legal person ou legal entity**. Este é o termo mais usado em inglês.

Esta é a definição de [legal person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_person) na Wikipédia:

> A legal person in legal context typically is a person (or less ambiguously, a legal entity)[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_person)—whether human or non-human—that is recognized as having certain privileges and obligations such as the legal capacity to enter into contracts, to sue, and to be sued.[3][4][5]
>
> However, the term "legal person" is ambiguous because it is often used as a synonym of terms that refer only to non-human legal entities, specifically in contradistinction to "natural person".[6][7]
>
> So there are of two kinds of legal entities, human and non-human: natural persons (also called physical persons) and juridical persons—also called juridic, juristic, artificial, legal, or fictitious persons, Latin: persona ficta—which are entities such as a corporation, firm, business or non-business group, or government agency, etc., that are treated in law as if they were persons.[4][8][9]

**Pessoa física é [natural person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_person) or physical person:**

> In jurisprudence, a natural person is a person (in legal meaning, i.e., one who has its own legal personality) that is an individual human being, as opposed to a legal person, which may be a private (i.e., business entity or non-governmental organization) or public (i.e., government) organization. Historically, a human being was not necessarily a natural person in some jurisdictions where slavery existed (subject of a property right) rather than a person.